# How to use project namespace in SLIME REPL

Tags: emacs, clojure, slime, swank, leiningen

I've installed lein with the swank plugin, Emacs, SLIME, and clojure-mode, and created a new project using lein new.  I've called the project clojure-test.  I then open clojure_test/src/clojure_test/core.clj in Emacs, and while in this file call `M-x clojure-jack-in`.  This opens up a SLIME window, which works fine; I can load code using `C-c C-l`, switch into my project namespace using `C-c M-p`, and use dependencies that I've added to the project.

The problem arises when, from the "user" namespace, I attempt to use the namespace for the project itself.  Calling `(use 'clojure-test)` inside of SLIME from the "user" namespace results in the following error:

```
Could not locate clojure_test__init.class or clojure_test.clj on classpath:
[Thrown class java.io.FileNotFoundException]
```

1. Why does Clojure search for these files?  The namespace is apparently already loaded, as I can switch into it via `C-c M-p`, but for some reason Clojure thinks these particular files are important to using the namespace.
2. How do I setup my project so that I can use the base namespace from SLIME?  Since lein is supposed to take care of this, what information am I not giving it that it needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace "clojure-test" should be in ./src/clojure_test.clj (./src is in the classpath by default unless you changed it in your project.clj file)

Did you put it in `src/clojure_test/core.clj` (which should have ns clojure-test.core instead) ?

See the documentation for libs at http://clojure.org/libs

Comment: Thanks, I must've deleted the .core at some point because I thought it was irrelevant; I didn't realize it was looking for namespaces via filename.